# Custom CSS to Change Main Menu Highlight Color for Selected on WEN Associate Theme

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use custom CSS to change the small highlighted bar under the selected item on the main menu of my website to match the brand colors. The default for WEN Associate theme is orange, but I'd like to change it to white. I would also like to change the block button background to the beige (#a58263) in the "Recruitment Services" block (see link - https://www.kelownahr.com/).

For the block button, I tried the code:

```
.wp-block-button_link {
    background-color: #a58263
!important
}
```

Nothing changed (still defaults to orange)

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) and its answers for why the link to your site is not sufficient, and include a [mre] (preferably using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon has `<>` on it in the editor toolbar)).

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hard to understand the first portion of your query however, this is your selector that determines the hover color of the border:

```
#site-navigation li a:hover,
#site-navigation li:hover > a,
#site-navigation li.current-menu-item > a,
#site-navigation li.current_page_item > a {
border-bottom: 3px solid #ff794c;
opacity: 1;
}
```

the second portion's answer is as such:

```
.wp-block-file .wp-block-file__button,
.wp-block-button__link{
background-color: #a58263 !important;}
```